# How to specify many relationship types in a @Relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have two nodes user and account and the relationship between them is any one of the 25 relationship. 
My Query is

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:rel1|rel2|rel3|rel4]->(a:Account) WHERE u.login_id=~('(?i).*'+{fulltextsearch}+'.*') RETURN u as User,r as acronym
```

My user pojo is

```
public class User{

    @GraphId
    private Long id;    

    String fulltextsearch;   

    String user_id; 

    String status; 


 //@Relationship(type = "rel1", direction= Relationship.OUTGOING)
    Acronym acronym;
    public Acronym getAcronym() {
    return acronym;
    }


    private Set<Account> accounts;

    public User() {

    }

    public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
    return status;
    }


    public String getFulltextsearch() {
    return fulltextsearch;
    }


    public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
    }


    public void setAccounts(Set<Account> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
    }   

    }
```

I am confused in writing my user pojo with multiple relatioships. 
can I give @Relatioship for multiple relatioship with OR.

like this `@Relationship(type = "rel1 | rel2", direction= Relationship.OUTGOING)`

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot supply multiple relationship types to the `@Relationship`. You will have to declare them independently in your entity:

```
  @Relationship(type = "rel1", direction= Relationship.OUTGOING)
  Acronym acronymRel1;

  @Relationship(type = "rel2", direction= Relationship.OUTGOING)
  Acronym acronymRel2;
```

You can write a custom query to fetch all Acronyms based on a set of relationship types.